# How to calculate current streak of conditional number, and excluding blanks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

it is my first post on stackoverflow so please bare with me if I'm not too familiar with everything around here.
Here is my issue :

```
Number of connections
 1777
 2500
 4227
  355
11332
 8402
 1972
 2285
 1828
 2249
 1138
 4082
 4121
 1969
 4289
 2728
12000
13000
15000
13000
13250
```

I have this column that I complete every day. I would like to get the current streak when the number of connections is greater than `10000`, and that this number is updated everyday I input the new number of connections.
For example, today the streak would be `5` (`12000`, `13000`, `15000`, `13000`, `13250`), however if I input `3200` tomorrow, I would like the number to come back to 0.

I tried various solutions for this issue.
I have made a helping column called CONNECTIONS TO HIDE with

```
=IFS(
   [@[Number of connections]]=""; "";
   [@[Number of connections]]>10000; "Win";
   [@[Number of connections]]<10000; "Loss"
)
```

And then in the streak cell, the formula:

```
=COUNTA(Table8[CONNECTIONS TO HIDE]) -
 MATCH(2;INDEX(1/(Table8[CONNECTIONS TO HIDE]="Loss");0))
```

It did not work.

I tried a simpler approach with:

```
=COUNTA(Table8[Number of connections]) -
 MATCH(2;INDEX(1/(Table8[Number of connections]<10000);0))
```

but still without result.

The main issue here seems to be that I am unable to exclude blank cells, that will be filled later, from the formula. Indeed, when I simply drag my selection to the values I have already inputted instead of the whole column (with blanks), it works just fine.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is `INDEX(1/(Table8[Number of connections]="Loss");0)` supposed to be?

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake, I edited my post now. The formula was supposed to take into account the helping column (CONNECTIONS TO HIDE), and not the original column (Number of connections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use xmatch if it's available in your version of Excel to do a reverse search:

```
=ROWS(Table1)-XMATCH(TRUE,Table1[Number of connections]<10000,0,-1)
```

[image]

[image]

Then if you need to ignore blanks:

```
=LET(data,Table1[Number of connections],filter,FILTER(data,data<>""),COUNT(filter)-XMATCH(TRUE,filter<10000,0,-1))
```

assuming these functions are available to you.

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for your answer. However, it does not seems to work for my case. Perhaps because my blank cases are part of my table ? I have other columns and rows filled later than that date. To clarify, my column (Number of connections) does not end with the last value I entered. Idk if that helps

Comment: Have you tried the edit with the filter to ignore blank cells? I think that should be OK.

Comment: Hello Tom, Thank you again for your answer, I feel like we are getting closer. If it indeed counts the current streak, if I input a number lower than 10000, it does not seem to take it into account and therefore the number goes up by 1. I need to check again if it is an issue on my side but that is where I'm at right now.

Comment: Nevermind, I checked it again, must have made a mistake ! Thank you so much for your answer and your time. Hope you have a great day :)